# Вместо русских букв знаки вопроса в intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, кодировка, macos

Всем привет, не могу решить проблему с кодировкой. При выводе русских букв в терминале Intellij Idea выходят знаки вопроса. Но при этом если запускать файл в обычном терминале (у меня мак 2021 года с м1) то все выводится нормально. Везде где мог вроде поставил кодировку UTF-8. Как сделать нормальный вывод русских букв?
[image: Основной миникод]

[image: настройки кодировки]

Comment: попробуйте юникод(utf-16)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает =(

Answer (score 4):

Была такая же проблема. Помогло поставить кодировку **windows-1251**.

[image: Настройки]

Также обязательно конвертировать все файлы проекта в неё. Например внизу с правой стороны отображается кодировка текущего открытого файла.

[image: кодировка файла]

Там нужно установить **windows-1251**, после чего IDEA предложит конвертировать файл в новый формат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Правда есть риск, что весь кирилличный текст файла может поменяться на вопросительные знаки после конвертации его в другой формат.

Comment: Вопрос про mac os был, советы с кодировкой cp1251 для него не актуальны.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` в **Edit Configurations...** -> **VM options**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавял, не помогает =(

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398429/intellij-idea-terminal-special-characters/59617145#59617145
Я вводил это, у меня и польский и русский выводило, через полчаса снова на свои места вернулось

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос